# A browser searching program for a a specific site

Tags: javascript, python, html, c++, notepad++

Ok it seems as though my previous question was voted down and was broad (not specific enough) OK, so let me try  to be more specfic.

So there is this URL "WWW.SAMPLEURL.COM/FE8ETB8TBig7-BU.COM". On Monday this URL is the same, "WWW.SAMPLEURL.COM/FE8ETB8TBig7-BU.COM", on Tuesday its " "WWW.SAMPLEURL.COM/Ffrerfwerfewrf.COM", and on Wednesday its ""WWW.SAMPLEURL.COM/FEWEWEFRFR7-BU.COM", and so on and so forth. Everyday the characters between the "/" and ".com" change, as you can see, and you won't be able to go on the site without typing in the exact URL. So I want to build a program that can search the web until it reaches that URL, how will my program know when its on the correct URL, by the content of the website. I want to build a program that just tries different combination of characters in between the "/" and ".com", until it is successful.  So what should do? and what exactly do I need in order to achieve this.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) article, before posting questions.

Comment: Yes, that is the the question, how WILL your program be able to tell what is the correct URL? Unless there is a good way to find out, you will either: 1. Find out what the algorithm to calculate the URL is, 2. find someone that publishes the URL, or 3. go through 0000000000.COM to zzzzzzzzz.COM until you find the right combination. With about 90 variants per character, and 13 characters, that's A HUGE number to search - even if you can do 1000s a second, it will take days... So not really an option.

Comment: "what exactly do I need in order to achieve this": learn to program, learn to solve problems. Start doing that. Once you have something, and hit a specific technical problem you cannot solve, do research about it and if you still can't solve it, ask a question here. "How to start" or "what to do" questions are outside the scope of SO (i.e. off-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach String in ´List of all strings`
    request url
        if response code is 200 and response contains specific text
            return true
```

You will have two problems:

- Since the array ´List of all string´ will have more elements than the number pi hast decimal places.
- You may get in trouble with the host, since you are running an endless request loop on the server

In short: this idea has no effective solution.

P.S.: Maybe ask the host for the url ;-)

Comment: Thanks, showed me something, I did not see